# Trying to reach JSON outside function, returns TypeError

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to get JSON number outside function using Node.js.

Firstly, JSON is imported from URL:

```
var request = require('request');
var importedJSON;
request('http://private-38e18c-uzduotis.apiary-mock.com/config/cash-in', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            importedJSON = JSON.parse(body);
         }
        processInputData();
    }
);
```

Than object is added into variable :

```
function processInputData() {
    var X ;
    X = importedJSON.percents;
    //console.log(X);
    return XX;
}
```

After all, `console.log()` shows value, but when I want to make variable global :

```
var showX = processInputData();
console.log(showX);
```

I get stuck into wild error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'percents' of undefined`
I am lost, if anyone knows where I am missing the point. Many thanks for all possible help.

Looking forward,

Comment: Was your request callback `function (error, response, body) { ... }` triggered before? What were the arguments for response and body?

Comment: Where do you write the last code block? If it's outside your request callback, then it's expected

Comment: I can already feel this is a classic async JS problem. You try to do stuff with percents, but it hasn't been set yet because your request has not been returned.

Comment: @sjaham it could be a problem,  instead of `return XX;` i tried to use `return callback XX;` but without any result. How should I return my request?

Comment: Do I need additional dependencies for `async`, because now only `npm install request --save` from https://github.com/request/request was used.

Comment: You don't need any additional dependencies. You just have to make sure, that `request()` executed its callback before you access `importedJSON`. When you call processInputData() within the callback, this is the case. Wehn you call processInputData() from somewhere else, you had to ensure this yourself.

Comment: @Konstantin you mean something like this? `request('http://private-38e18c-uzduotis.apiary-mock.com/config/cash-in', processInputData, function (error, response, body) {...});` and then I am trying to call it `function processInputData(importedJSON) {...}`